# Javascript Select Options all at Once

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to update all options of a `<select>` element at once?

Depending on a prior option selected, I would like

```html
<select name="area" id="area" size="1" style="width: 150px"></select>
```

to change to (or something similar depending on the option selected):

```html
<select name="area" id="area" size="1" style="width: 150px">
    <option selected="" disabled="">Select An Area/Resource</option>
    <option value="1">cafe</option>
    <option value="2">lounge</option>
    <option value="3" disabled="">quiet area</option>
    <option value="4">tables</option>
</select>
```

The block of options is actually stored in a variable as you see them here:

```html
<option selected="" disabled="">Select An Area/Resource</option><option value="1">cafe</option><option value="2">lounge</option><option value="3" disabled="">quiet area</option><option value="4">tables</option>
```

Comment: what is your goal, can you give sample output?

Comment: Just use `innerHTML`? Why does your title say “select options all at once”? Do you want to _select_ them or _update_ them?

Comment: *"and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65645725/edit) is the JavaScript I tried"*

Comment: *"stored  in a variable"* that's not a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. It's just a matter of changing the `.innerHTML` of the `select` element.

```js
const options = '<option selected="" disabled="">Select An Area/Resource</option><option value="1">cafe</option><option value="2">lounge</option><option value="3" disabled="">quiet area</option><option value="4">tables</option>';

const list = document.querySelector("select");

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", function(){
  list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML === "" ? options : "";
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">check or uncheck to change the following list.<br>
<select name="area" id="area" size="1" style="width: 150px"></select>
```